# change value of a nested object using setState hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, setstate

Need to change `isClicked` on click like a toggle to `!isClicked`. It renders JSX styles for a button click.

My data:

```js
const [isApply, setIsApply] = useState([
    {
        "0": {
            "isClicked": false,
            "isExpand": false,
            "uni": "NSBM"
        }
    },
    {
        "1": {
            "isClicked": false,
            "isExpand": false,
            "uni": "NSBM"
        }
    },
    {
        "2": {
            "isClicked": false,
            "isExpand": false,
            "uni": "SLIIT"
        }
    },
    {
        "3": {
            "isClicked": false,
            "isExpand": false,
            "uni": "SLIIT ACADEMY"
        }
    },
    {
        "4": {
            "isClicked": false,
            "isExpand": false,
            "uni": "NIBM"
        }
    },
    {
        "5": {
            "isClicked": false,
            "isExpand": false,
            "uni": "NIBM"
        }
    }
])
```

```js
const apply = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked button id: ", e.currentTarget.id);
    console.log(isApply);
    setIsApply(...)
};
```

Need to change isClicked on click like a toggle(!isClicked). It renders jsx styles for a button click. Because it's a nested object and object keys are generated with button click ID it makes it harder to set the state of isClicked need help

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) talks about how nested state is not a great idea. I ran into the same issue just a few days ago and made use of reactjs flux

Comment: I suggest you change your state to an object or keep it as an array but add a new property called id to each object to simplify the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing something wrong when spreading object. You have to consider [object spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

When object spreading, The placement of spread operator could effect on the action you're performing.

**✗ Wrong**

```js
{ isClicked: !state[key]?.isClicked, ...state[key] }
```

Here even you're updating `isClicked` value it's not effect on object because  since you're adding `...state[key]` after updating `isClicked` value. It replaces the original object by itself.

**✔ Correct**

```js
{ ...state[key], isClicked: !state[key]?.isClicked }
```

Here you put your current state by adding `...state[key]` and then updating the `isClicked` value of that particular object.

[Here is the working Example with React.](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-silence-dhe1s?file=/src/App.js)